# Disable fontlock (syntax highlighting) for \newcommand

Tags: emacs, auctex

The syntax highlighting for `\newcommand` in my editor (Aquamacs/AucTeX) looks like this:

[image]

I don't like it because everything inside the definition has the same light blue colour. By contrast, if I use a `\def` instead, I get the following highlighting, which I much prefer.

[image]

According to **[the AucTeX manual, §3.1.1](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Fontification-of-macros.html#General-macro-classes)**, AucTeX keeps a list of "function" keywords in the variable `font-latex-match-function-keywords`. It currently contains: `begin`, `end`, `pagenumbering`, `thispagestyle`, `pagestyle`, `nofiles`, `includeonly`, `bibliographystyle`, `documentstyle`, `documentclass`, `newcommand`, `newenvironment`, `newlength`, `newtheorem`, `newcounter`, `renewenvironment`, `renewcommand`, `renewtheorem`, `usepackage`, `fbox`, `mbox`, `sbox`, `vspace`, `hspace`, `thinspace`, `negthinspace`, `enspace`, `enskip`, `quad`, `qquad`, `nonumber`, `centering`, `TeX`, `LaTeX`.

I would like to remove from that list all those commands that tend to take long arguments, namely: `newenvironment`, `renewenvironment`, `newcommand`, `renewcommand`, `fbox`, `mbox` and `sbox`. What LISP instructions can I put into my `.emacs` file to do that?

Comment: To me, the most annoying feature is that a `\chapter` command in a `\newcommand` is formatted like it were in text.

Comment: Oh? I don't have that problem: see http://i.stack.imgur.com/nnbPj.png

Comment: The "foo" in the argument of `\chapter` is bigger; that's what I was referring to.

Comment: Oh, I'm with you now. Yeah, I guess it might be tricky to fix that. The highlighting of `\chapter`'s argument would have to depend on the context.

Comment: There is an AUCTeX function to check whether point is inside the argument of a macro, but I don't know where to put this check, actually I'm not comfortable with font locking hacking in Emacs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is to override built-in fontification with what you want.  You can do that using the `font-latex-add-keywords` function.  For more information about the argument specification, see [Fontification of macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Fontification-of-macros) in the [AUCTeX manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.index.html).

To change fontification of the macros you mentioned, you can add this to your `.emacs`:

```el
(defun my-font-latex-add-custom-keywords ()
  (eval-after-load "font-latex"
    '(font-latex-add-keywords '(("newenvironment" "*{[[")
                                ("renewenvironment" "*{[[")
                                ("newcommand" "*|{\\[[")
                                ("renewcommand" "*|{\\[[")
                                ("providecommand" "*|{\\[[")
                                ("fbox" "")
                                ("mbox" "")
                                ("sbox" ""))
                              'function)))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my-font-latex-add-custom-keywords)
```

Comment: One minor improvement could be to fontify the *first* argument of, say, `\newcommand`, but not the second. So `\newcommand\john{blahblah}` would highlight the `\john` but not the `blahblah`. My *guess* is this could be done quite easily by modifying the current entry `("newcommand" "*|{\\[[{")` in `font-latex-match-function-keywords-local`. But I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Answer updated. I changed the fontification definitions removing the last `{` from all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the Font Lock Function Name Face (font-lock-function-name-face):

- `M-x customize-face`
- Choose `font-lock-function-name-face`
- Uncheck `Foreground`
- Press `Save for future sessions` button

Comment: This changes only the face of the function name (for all Emacs modes, not just AUCTeX), not fontification of arguments.

Comment: @giordano In my versions of AUCTeX (11.87) and Emacs (23.4.1), this changes the color of the function and the aspect of the code of the function...

Comment: Ok, you're right, but it isn't what John asked for.

Comment: Thanks Paul, that's a nice alternative approach. I'll stick with Giordano's approach because it allows fine-grained control over exactly which parts are highlighted and which aren't.

Answer (score 1):

My setup in order to get rid of this fontification annoyance started from [giordano's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120755/73317) but has evolved a little bit as I discovered problems.

## What I do

- In the [Emacs initialization file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) (`~/.emacs.d/init.el`, `~/.emacs.el`, etc.):

```el
(require 'tex-site)   ; Load AUCTeX

(defun my-font-latex-remove-unwanted-fontification-keywords ()
  (dolist (command '("newenvironment"
                     "renewenvironment"
                     "newcommand"
                     "renewcommand"
                     "providecommand"
                     "fbox"
                     "mbox"
                     "sbox"))
    (setq-default font-latex-match-function-keywords-local
                  (remove (assoc-string
                           command font-latex-match-function-keywords-local)
                          font-latex-match-function-keywords-local))))

(eval-after-load "font-latex"
  '(my-font-latex-remove-unwanted-fontification-keywords))

(defun my-font-latex-add-custom-keywords ()
  ;; Add our fontification specs for these keywords
  (font-latex-add-keywords '(("newenvironment" "*{[[")
                             ("renewenvironment" "*{[[")
                             ("newcommand" "*|{\\[[")
                             ("renewcommand" "*|{\\[[")
                             ("providecommand" "*|{\\[[")
                             ("fbox" "")
                             ("mbox" "")
                             ("sbox" ""))
                           'function))

(defun my-LaTeX-mode-hook ()
  (message "Loading <insert your name here>'s LaTeX mode hook")
  ;; Use font-latex.el for fontification
  (require 'font-latex)
  (my-font-latex-add-custom-keywords))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'my-LaTeX-mode-hook)
```

- In `~/.emacs.d/auctex/style/xparse.el`:

```el
;; File created by <your name here>. Loaded after, and overrides part of the
;; settings done by xparse.el from the AUCTeX installation.

(TeX-add-style-hook
 "xparse"
 (lambda ()
   (when (and (featurep 'font-latex)
          (eq TeX-install-font-lock 'font-latex-setup))
     (message "Adding <your name here>'s own keywords for `font-latex' (%s)"
              "xparse style file")
     (font-latex-add-keywords
              '(("DeclareDocumentCommand" "|{\\")
                ("NewDocumentCommand" "|{\\")
                ("RenewDocumentCommand" "|{\\")
                ("ProvideDocumentCommand" "|{\\")
                ("DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand" "|{\\")
                ("NewExpandableDocumentCommand" "|{\\")
                ("RenewExpandableDocumentCommand" "|{\\")
                ("ProvideExpandableDocumentCommand" "|{\\")
                ("DeclareDocumentEnvironment" "{")
                ("NewDocumentEnvironment" "{")
                ("RenewDocumentEnvironment" "{")
                ("ProvideDocumentEnvironment" "{"))
                  'function)))
 LaTeX-dialect)
```

## Explanations

### Remove built-in keywords we want to redefine

Let's start with the first bit:

```el
(defun my-font-latex-remove-unwanted-fontification-keywords ()
  (dolist (command '("newenvironment"
                     "renewenvironment"
                     "newcommand"
                     "renewcommand"
                     "providecommand"
                     "fbox"
                     "mbox"
                     "sbox"))
    (setq-default font-latex-match-function-keywords-local
                  (remove (assoc-string
                           command font-latex-match-function-keywords-local)
                          font-latex-match-function-keywords-local))))

(eval-after-load "font-latex"
  '(my-font-latex-remove-unwanted-fontification-keywords))
```

This is adapted from [advice found in the AUCTeX manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Deactivating-defaults-of-built_002din-keyword-classes). Strictly speaking, and unless I missed something, this part is only required in case some [AUCTeX style file](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Style-Files) would have the strange idea of redeclaring the keywords in question (`\newcommand`, `\renewcommand`, etc.). Indeed, such style files run *after* `LaTeX-mode-hook`, and therefore can override whatever we do with `font-latex-add-keywords` from this hook. Apart from this reason, doing so cleans up (keyword, syntax) pairs from the default value of `font-latex-match-function-keywords-local`, so that when I later readd the same keywords with my preferred syntax specification (see below), they occur only **once** in the resulting value of `font-latex-match-function-keywords-local`. Note that:

- Since in the end, this code only does `setq-default` calls, it doesn't need to be run from the `LaTeX-mode-hook`; thus, we save a bit of time doing this way.
- I use `assoc-string` instead of `TeX-assoc-string` (still mentioned in the online AUCTeX manual, but already fixed in the AUCTeX repository) because the latter has been removed from AUCTeX in 2017 ([commit d3d321a8d2](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/?id=d3d321a8d210b5b358af63d850444e827ba0826f)).
- As the AUCTeX manual mentions, since it somehow fiddles with a `font-latex` internal, this piece of code is not guaranteed to continue to work *as is* in future versions of `font-latex`.
- I apply the same fontification changes to `\fbox`, `\mbox` and `\sbox` as to `\newcommand`, `\renewcommand`, etc., because in my opinion, the fontification of the argument is no more desirable for these box commands than for `\newcommand` and friends.

### Redefine fontification specs for the removed built-in keywords

The second bit is essentially the same as in [giordano's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120755/73317):

```el
(defun my-font-latex-add-custom-keywords ()
  ;; Add our fontification specs for these keywords
  (font-latex-add-keywords '(("newenvironment" "*{[[")
                             ("renewenvironment" "*{[[")
                             ("newcommand" "*|{\\[[")
                             ("renewcommand" "*|{\\[[")
                             ("providecommand" "*|{\\[[")
                             ("fbox" "")
                             ("mbox" "")
                             ("sbox" ""))
                           'function))

(defun my-LaTeX-mode-hook ()
  (message "Loading <insert your name here>'s LaTeX mode hook")
  ;; Use font-latex.el for fontification
  (require 'font-latex)
  (my-font-latex-add-custom-keywords))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'my-LaTeX-mode-hook)
```

This readds the keywords we just removed, but with my preferred syntax: don't use special colors for the replacement text of macros and environments (see below for an explanation of the `"*|{\\[["` syntax).

Note: since `my-font-latex-add-custom-keywords` calls `font-latex-add-keywords` which, in this particular case, modifies the automatically buffer-local variable `font-latex-match-function-keywords-local`, `my-font-latex-add-custom-keywords` must be run from buffers where `font-latex` is active (buffers in LaTeX mode). This is why I call this function from `LaTeX-mode-hook` as opposed to using `(eval-after-load "font-latex" ...)`. Indeed, the latter could rerun `...` from any buffer from which `(load "font-latex")` is executed, even several times in the same Emacs session—this would set buffer-local variables in the wrong buffer(s).

### Override undesirable fontification specs that come from AUCTeX style files

This is the final bit, where we create the file `~/.emacs.d/auctex/style/xparse.el` (see above for its contents). This file takes care of commands defined by [xparse](https://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) such as `\NewDocumentCommand`, `\NewDocumentEnvironment`, etc. For these, the technique described above doesn't work, because the corresponding `font-latex` keywords are not part of `font-latex-built-in-keyword-classes`; rather, they are added on-demand by an [AUCTeX style file](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Style-Files), namely the `xparse.el` file that is part of current AUCTeX installations. This particular style file is only activated when your document uses the `xparse` package, and the hook it defines (added with `TeX-add-style-hook`) is run *after* `LaTeX-mode-hook`. Therefore, calling `font-latex-add-keywords` from `LaTeX-mode-hook` in order to override syntax specification of LaTeX commands declared in AUCTeX's `xparse.el` file doesn't work, since hooks defined in AUCTeX style files are run *after* `LaTeX-mode-hook`.

Fortunately, there is an easy cure: as shown above, all one has to do is to create our own style file as shown above and put it in `~/.emacs.d/auctex/style/`, since it is a hand-written AUCTeX style file (as opposed to `~/.emacs.d/auctex/auto/`, which is for automatically-generated style files<sup>1</sup>).

Note: my style file for `xparse` contains lines such as:

```el
("NewDocumentEnvironment" "{")
```

The syntax of the second string is explained [in the AUCTeX manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Fontification-of-macros). In this case, it tells AUCTeX to only give a special color to the first brace-delimited argument of `\NewDocumentEnvironment`. This way, visual attention is only drawn on `\NewDocumentEnvironment` and the environment name, so that I get this kind of result:

[image: Screenshot with good fontification]

Had I used this specification instead:

```el
("NewDocumentEnvironment" "{{")
```

a second argument would have been colorized, like this:

[image: Screenshot with bad (too much) fontification]

Nothing dramatic, but I believe this is more distracting than helpful (when I browse LaTeX code, I want to quickly see which command or environment starts where; the number and type of its arguments don't need to stand out).

Finally, let's explain the fontification specification for `\newcommand`. If you do `C-h v font-latex-built-in-keyword-classes` you shoud see a line like this:

```el
("newcommand" "*|{\\[[{")
```

This means that, by default in the version of AUCTeX used here, `\newcommand` is declared to have the following properties:

- it features a star form (`*`);
- the first argument is either (`|`) brace-delimited (`{`) or a control sequence token (`\`, which must be written as `\\` inside an Emacs Lisp string, according to the [read syntax for strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-for-Strings.html#Syntax-for-Strings) defined in the [GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/elisp.html));
- the two following arguments are delimited by brackets (`[`, as usual for optional arguments in LaTeX);
- the final argument is delimited by braces (`{`): this is the macro replacement text, which is quite nasty to display all in the same color, in particular a color that makes it difficult to concentrate on. So, by replacing this with:

```el
("newcommand" "*|{\\[[")
```

we suppress special fontification of the macro replacement text, and by using

```el
("newcommand" "*|{\\")
```

we would even suppress special fontification of the two optional arguments (however, they are not displayed in a distracting color with `"*|{\\[["`, so they don't really bother me).

## When style files are not loaded

In some cases, you can have documents that should benefit from a style file, but don't. This may of course cause fontification problems. In order to diagnose this, I examine the `*Messages*` buffer after opening or reverting the file in question. If for instance the file has `\usepackage{xparse}` but `\NewDocumentCommand` isn't fontified as I specified, one can suspect that my xparse.el in ~/.emacs.d/auctex/style/ isn't loaded. This is easy to see thanks to the `(message ...)` call I put in this xparse.el. I have the same kind of message when my additions to `LaTeX-mode-hook` are run, therefore in such cases, the diagnostic is obtained by seeing the message printed by my additions to `LaTeX-mode-hook` but not the one from my own xparse.el.

Now, why would that happen? Well, the style system in AUCTeX isn't very simple, but I figured that what I'm talking about here happens when the name of the .tex (or .sty, .cls...) file I'm working on has the same stem as an already-loaded, non-empty AUCTeX style. For instance, when I call my documents doc.tex, I don't see my xparse fontification even if I have `(setq TeX-parse-self t)` in my [Emacs initialization file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) (always) and the document has `\usepackage{xparse}`. This is because the AUCTeX style machinery has already loaded a style named `doc`, apparently corresponding to tex/latex/base/doc.sty, and therefore AUCTeX mistakenly believes it is not useful to parse my doc.tex (it only records the name `doc` in the list of loaded styles `TeX-style-hook-list`, and thus can't tell the difference between my doc.tex and the official tex/latex/base/doc.sty).

Another avatar of the same problem can be reproduced by first opening /path/to/unique-filename.tex containing:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \somecommand { m }
  { }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

(`\usepackage{xcolor}` is there to ensure that the AUCTeX style information recorded for `unique-filename` won't be empty—there is a check for emptyness of the style information when AUCTeX decides on “should we run `TeX-auto-apply` for this file?”)

then opening /path/to/other/unique-filename.tex containing:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \somecommand { m }
  { }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

The first document doesn't have its `\NewDocumentCommand` fontified; this is as expected, since it (mistakenly from the LaTeX point of view) doesn't load `xparse`. However, the second file *also* doesn't have its `\NewDocumentCommand` fontified, whereas my xparse.el style file says it ought to have. The reason is that when loading or reverting the second file, AUCTeX sees that it has already non-empty style information for `unique-filename` (that was loaded for the first unique-filename.tex), and therefore 
it doesn't deem it useful to parse the second unique-filename.tex, despite my having set `TeX-parse-self` to `t`.

In order to work around this, you can set up a key binding that runs a command doing `(TeX-run-style-hooks "xparse")`. Actually, since I already have something like the following in my Emacs-wide setup:

```el
(defun my-unconditionally-revert-buffer ()
  "Revert buffer from file on disk without asking any question."
  (interactive)
  (revert-buffer t t))

(put #'my-unconditionally-revert-buffer 'disabled t)

(global-set-key [f5] #'my-unconditionally-revert-buffer)
```

I have extended it so that the `f5` key also runs `(TeX-run-style-hooks "xparse")` in LaTeX buffers:

```el
(defun my-unconditionally-revert-buffer-and-rerun-style-hooks ()
  (interactive)
  (my-unconditionally-revert-buffer)
  (dolist (style '("xparse"))
    (TeX-run-style-hooks style)))

(put #'my-unconditionally-revert-buffer-and-rerun-style-hooks 'disabled t)

(define-key LaTeX-mode-map [f5]
  #'my-unconditionally-revert-buffer-and-rerun-style-hooks)
```

So, when the problem arises, I first save the buffer, then press `f5` to reload the file (not particularly useful after saving) *and* parse it to gather relevant AUCTeX style information (it gets parsed because I have `(setq TeX-parse-self t)` in my [Emacs initialization file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html)).

---

**Footnote**

1. AUCTeX can detect when commands such as `\newcommand` and `\newenvironment` are used and automatically generate style information from calls to these commands in your `.tex` or `.sty` files (also `.cls`, `.ltx`, `.dtx` and others; see [Automatic Customization](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Automatic) in the AUCTeX manual, the `TeX-file-extensions` variable and the `TeX-auto-generate` AUCTeX command).